# Rails 4 default respond_to for ajax controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails controller where every action has the same respond_to block for every action, eg:

```
def some_action
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to :back }
    format.js   { render layout: false }
  end
end
```

Is there a way that I can set this as the default response for all actions? I know that I can use

```
respond_to :html, :js
```

at the top of the  controller, but can this be used to set the specific responses for each format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all actions to respond exactly the same, move the `respond_to` block into a method.

```
def some_action
  # do things
  respond
end 

def another_action
  # do more things
  respond
end

def special_action
  # do special things
  respond
end

private

def respond
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to :back }
    format.js   { render layout: false }
  end
end
```

This will DRY up your controller, which I assume was the question.

Comment: This is what I've done, I was just wondering whether there was an even DRYer way that didn't require the same call in every action.

Answer (score 1):

Going though [respond_with](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/respond_with) and [respond_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/InstanceMethods/respond_to) documentation and source code. You can either

#### Use `respond_to`

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      flash[:notice] = 'User was successfully created.'
      format.html { redirect_to(@user) }
      format.xml { render xml: @user }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.xml { render xml: @user }
    end
  end
end
```

---

#### OR `respond_with`

```
respond_to :html, :xml

def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  flash[:notice] = 'User was successfully created.' if @user.save
  respond_with(@user)
end
```

---

A work around is to create your own custom `respond` method, or manually check for the `mime` type as follows:

#### ****NOTE: this is a really bad practice, I recommend sticking to conventions.

```
def some_action
  render json: {"a" => "s"} if request.format.json? 
  render :some_action if request.format.html? 
end
```